# Can I theme fields depending on view or block that contains them?

Tags: 7, views, entities, blocks

Let's say I have a contact content type with fields address, tel, fax, etc. My task is to create 2 views - with following markup:

First view

```
<ul>
   <li>[address]</li>
   <li>[tel]</li>
   <li>[fax]</li>
</ul>
```

Second view

```
<div>
   <div>[address]</div>
   <div>[tel]</div>
   <div>[fax]</div>
</div>
```

The above is just a simple example, in general I want to know how much control can I get over fields html markup, can I somehow change it depending on view or block that contains the field or even depending on field itself. If so - what is the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [introduction for views2](http://drupal.org/node/352970). To read manuals exactly for your views version, use [Advanced Help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module.

You can template everything, overriding template files in complex manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are some theme plugins available depending upon the you are using (for example for bootstrap theme, there exists a module named [views_bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap). So if you can give various formats to your contents.

Also you can change the style settings for each field in views, as shown below: [image: style settings in views]

you can change field wrappers, add your own classes to your wrappers etc..